# How do I typedef a function type that returns a function of the same type in C++?

Tags: c++, typedef

I would like to know how to declare a function type that returns a function of the same type using `typedef` in C++.

While watching a Golang talk given by Rob Pike on lexical scanning, I came across the following code snippet,

```golang
type stateFn func(*Scanner) stateFn
```

This is the exact behavior that I would like to replicate in C++.

I have tried using the following type definition,

```
typedef state_fn state_fn(Scanner &);
```

But this gives me the error `function returning function is not allowed`.
Is it possible at all to do something like this? If not, how do I do something similar?

Comment: If you had that type, how would you use it?

Comment: "using typedef" - note that `typedef` is more or less obsolete in modern C++. You probably want to use `using` in new code.

Comment: (As a note for the OP: While the duplicate source is for C and not C++, the same rules regarding recursive types still apply.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return functions in C++. See [dcl.fct]p10:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things.

However, you can return some form of callable (that may be wrapping a function of the same type).